# immediate succesor with calendar input

Tags: python, list, input, cycle

The task is to make an immediate sucessor so that it reads the input from the user if it is in the list, and consequently it selects the next item in the list (or the first in case the last item in the list has been the input).

This is what I have:

```
import sys
input_date = input("Enter the date in YYYY-MM-DD format: ")
year, month, day = input_date.split("-")
year = int(year)

valid_months = ["01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12"]
valid_days = [
    "01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10",
    "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", 
    "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31"
]
thirty_day_months = ["04", "06", "09", "11"]
if not year in range(1960, 2004 + 1):
    print("Year must be in the range 1960 to 2004")
    sys.exit(1)
if not month in valid_months:
    print("Month must be in the for MM, and between 01 and 12")
    sys.exit(2)
if month == "02":
  valid_days.remove("31")
  valid_days.remove("30")
  valid_days.remove("29")
  if not day in valid_days:
    print("Error: invalid day (1)")
    sys.exit(3)
    # validate day for february
if month in thirty_day_months:
  valid_days.remove("31")
  if not day in valid_days:
    print("Error: invalid day (2)")
    sys.exit(4)
    # validate day for 30-day months
else:
  input_date = (f"{year}-{month}-{day}")
  print(input_date)
    # validate day for 31-day months
```

How do I do that? Also, no option for leap years is included.

I have been trying to make an immediate succesor calendar program, but I do not know how to cycle with lists rather than integers...

Answer (score 0):

here are some ideas how the task could be done. we are going to use the datetime module from python. this can do most of the handling you did in your code, including leap year and so on.
you can modify it for your own needs.

````
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

while True: # implement to check if the input year is in the required range
    inp = input('year-month-day: ') or '2000-02-28'
    my_date = datetime.strptime(inp, '%Y-%m-%d') # create datetime object
    if 1960 <= my_date.year <= 2004:
        break 
    
new_date = my_date + timedelta(days = 1) # add 1 day to the datetime object

if my_date.month == new_date.month: # if month has not changed
    print(datetime.strftime(new_date, '%Y-%m-%d')) # # print input date + 1 day
else:  
    print(my_date.replace(day=1)) # # set date to the 1. of the month
```
````